# How to read a table in an HTML page, without an ID or DIV in Java

Tags: java, html

I want to read a table, which is an HTML page, but it hasn't any id to detect it. 
So the web page is this [one](http://www.fantagiaveno.it/goalpartita.asp)

And what I want to have is just this table, with its values:
[image]

In Java I want to have two ArrayList of Players (which are object); this first is for "Goal Vittoria", the second one for "Goal Pareggio";

```
 public class Player {

    private String surname;
    private String team;
}
```

I've already used the library JSoup, which is very well done, but the problem, is that the web page is not well organized, it is difficult to read all of them. 
This is what I could do:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.fantagiaveno.it/goalpartita.asp");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);

    Element table = doc.select("table").first();

    Iterator<Element> ite = table.select("td[class=TestoTabella8]").iterator();

    ite.next(); // first one is image, skip it
    int index = 0;
    while(index<30){
        Element par = ite.next();
        String text = par.text();
        int hash = par.hashCode();
    if(hash!=292270948){

    System.out.println(text);
    }


    index++;
    }
```

The problem is that the output is not as I want, because I can't get the title and/or understand if the Player is from the first type (Goal Vittoria) or the second one (Goal Pareggio). Also the index I set 30, isn't always correct, because more players can be set (the MAX nummber can be 10 for both Goal Vittoria and Goal Pareggio). Any suggests ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that the output is not as I want, because I can't get the title >and/or understand if the Player is from the first type (Goal Vittoria) or the >second one (Goal Pareggio)
>   Select all the tables and loop through them to check the title.  If the title >matches then start your iterator

In the link you posted, the title of the table is stored in the first td of the first row.  Use a JSoup selector to get the value of the first td in the first row, and then check if this value starts with 'GOAL VITTORIA' or 'GOAL PAREGGIO'

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.fantagiaveno.it/goalpartita.asp");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);

        Elements elements = doc.body().select(".TitoloTabellaBlu");

        for (Element element : elements) {
            String val = element.html();
            if (val.startsWith("GOAL VITTORIA")) {                    
                Iterator<Element> ite = element.parent().parent().select("td[class=TestoTabella8]").iterator();
                ite.next(); // first one is image, skip it 
                int index = 0;

                while (ite.hasNext()) {
                    //your code here                    
                }
            } else if (val.startsWith("GOAL PAREGGIO")) {                    
                Iterator<Element> ite2 = element.parent().parent().select("td[class=TestoTabella8]").iterator();
                while (ite2.hasNext()) {

                }
            }

        }
```

> Updated
>
> Also the index I set 30, isn't always correct

As above, use the    .hasNext()   method on the iterator.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can't compile, because for String val = element.find("tr").first().closest("td").val(); I can't find the method find for type Element.

Comment: try this: String val = input.select("tr:first-child td:first-child").val();  I have edited the post again

Comment: Thank you again, but the code doesn't enter in the first if. Also do you mean input is elemenet, isn't it ?

Comment: I have made another change to the selectors and run the code to confirm it works

Comment: Thank you for your effort ! It work quite well, but in the mean time, I found a solution, which works better, with the use of ite.next().html() and StringTokeneizer. Thank you in all case for your help, which has been very usefull for my problem !